# New Note global action not coming in Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, global-actions, publisher

I have moved the new note action in publisher layout but new note isn't coming. Other global actions are coming. Is there any other setting too ?

Comment: Does the record you are viewing has record type assigned to it?

Comment: @manjit_singh gloal actions comes on top of the page in lightning. I don't think record type has something to do with it

Answer (score 1):

Global actions works in spring'17. Previously versions allow add them but they don't appear.

> ## [Take More Actions from the Global Actions Menu](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_general_lex_global_action_menu_enhanced.htm#rn_forcecom_lex_setup_global_action_menu_enhanced)
>
> Create records, log calls, take notes, and launch canvas, Visualforce, and Lightning component actions from anywhere in Lightning Experience. The Global Actions menu (Global Actions Menu ) now displays nearly all global actions from the Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions section of the global publisher layout. This change applies to Lightning Experience only.
>
> You might have noticed that we said “nearly all.” The Global Actions menu doesn’t support the standard Chatter actions Post, File, Poll, Link, Question, and Thanks.

Comment: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_general_lex_global_action_menu_enhanced.htm#rn_forcecom_lex_setup_global_action_menu_enhanced